# How do I add a period after @viewDataTeam.ID to display an image?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to display an image and the file name is from a viewData so here's what I did

```
<img src="~/Images/team_logo/@viewDataTeam.ID.png" width="50" />
```

but it gives me an error because it thinks that the `.png` is a method but what I meant for `.png` is a file extension.

I could use something like this `<img src="~/Images/team_logo/@viewDataTeam.ID _.png" width="50" />` then rename the image to `2 _.png` but is there another way so I could use `2.png`?

Comment: Why do you not just pass the formatted value to the view? But you can always use `src="~/Images/team_logo/@(viewDataTeam.ID).png"`

Comment: The data is from the database. Thanks. It works

Comment: Create a view model or use `ViewBag` and format the file name in the server method!